# Programming for Windows Mobile in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe5

So Delphi now supports programming for Windows, MacOS, Android & iOS. Is there any way to use Delphi (XE5) to write programs for Windows Mobile?

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows Mobile"? Do you mean Windows CE (old) based "Windows Mobile 6" or "Windows Phone 8" which is completely different than Windows Mobile, and not based on CE?

Comment: @WarrenP I mean all of what you mentioned!

Comment: There is no way with any tool or language to write one application that runs on both Win Mobile 6, and WinPhone 7, and WinPhone 8.  Not even with Microsoft tools.  Delphi has never supported any Microsoft mobile operating systems, but it is on the roadmap for the future to support Windows Mobile 8, I believe.

Comment: Any news about Windows (Mobile = Windows 10 on phones) platform? maybe newest release of RAD Studio (10 Seattle) added some new features?

Answer (score 5):

You may look at [Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/) compiler from [RemObjects](http://www.remobjects.com/), they have support for many platforms, including WinRT, iOS and Android, Here's a quote from their website:

> Oxygene 6 is out now, supporting 3 major target platforms: .NET, WinRT
>   and Mono, Java and Android and NEW! native Cocoa development for Mac
>   and iOS. the same language lets you targets all three platforms, and
>   produces 100% native output for the respective platform

Oxygene isn't a Delphi product, but it was bundled with Rad Studio as Delphi Prism

Comment: Looks like Oxygene can do WinPhone: http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/platforms/windowsphone.aspx

Comment: Oxygene lets you leverage your knowledge of Pascal syntax, but be aware that its approach is based on giving you Pascal syntax access to the frameworks already on the platform, so if you want to learn Windows Phone Development, you'll need to read the Microsoft docs and learn how to use the Windows Phone 8 APIs and SDKs, with the only difference being that you code in Pascal instead of C#.   You can then write apps for Windows Phone 8 as well as Windows Store Apps for Windows 8.    These apps will generally not be portable to iOS and Android.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi XE5 targets Windows desktop, 32 and 64 bit, 32 bit MacOS, iOS (ARM) and Android (ARM). It does not target any flavour of Windows mobile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Lazarus. http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org
It has support for WinCE.

Google for lazarus wince and you'll see a sizeable list of references.
Don't have experience with WinCE myself.

Comment: WinCE is kind of old school now. A bit like Win95! I doubt that FPC targets WinPhone

Comment: We actually work with a rather *new* barcode scanner (Motorola MT-2070) which runs WinCE.

Comment: @JerryDodge That does not make this question be about WinCE though

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course not, just expressing the fact that even though it's old, it's not yet obsolete.

Comment: Sadly, Symbol/Motorola barcode scanner tech running CE is really sadly out of date. Check out the hardware specs.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi XE5 targets Windows 32bit, Windows 64bit, MacOS 32bit, iOS, Android and Web. It does not target any Windows Mobile.

You can download lazarus from http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org
It has support for WinCE.

You can upgrade to Delphi 10.1 Berlin or even wait for Delphi 10.2 Godzilla. Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2 includes Windows 10 development and thus the ability to convert your Win32 or Win64 app to an AppX file. An AppX file is used to run apps on Windows 10. This includes Desktop, Xbox One, HoloLense, Mobile, Tablet, IoT, etc. Although I believe Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2 conversion to AppX uses the Desktop Bridge from Microsoft and thus your converted app might probably only run on Windows 10 desktop and Windows 10 tablet.